# AWS EC2 disk full, cannot release space

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, disk

I am using an EC2 instance to run a node app. I logged into the server after a while only to realise that the server has run out of disk space. After debugging, I realised that logs are taking up space. I deleted the 3.3Gb log file. However, even after the cleanup there is no space. What should I do?

Here are the commands I ran:

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           496M  8.0K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

---

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -n
0   /proc
0   /sys
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /dev
8.0K    /snap
16K /lost+found
24K /root
800K    /tmp
6.4M    /etc
11M /run
14M /sbin
16M /bin
246M    /boot
331M    /home
397M    /opt
429M    /var
538M    /lib
2.1G    /usr
3.7G    /data
7.7G    /
```

I deleted a 3.3G log file in `/data` and ran `du` again

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h
0   /proc
0   /sys
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /dev
8.0K    /snap
16K /lost+found
24K /root
800K    /tmp
6.4M    /etc
11M /run
14M /sbin
16M /bin
246M    /boot
331M    /home
352M    /data
397M    /opt
429M    /var
538M    /lib
2.1G    /usr
4.4G    /
```

---

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           496M  8.0K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Although the `/data` directory is now reduced to 352M, still `df` still shows 100% disk utilization. What am I missing?**

Referring to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253655/47050, here is the output of `strace`

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ strace -e statfs df /
statfs("/", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=2016361, f_bfree=4096, f_bavail=0, f_files=1024000, f_ffree=617995, f_fsid={2136106470, -680157247}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=4128}) = 0
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8065444 8049060         0 100% /
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

**UPDATE**

I ran

`sudo lsof | grep deleted`

and found

```
node\x20/ 22318           deploy   12w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
node\x20/ 22318           deploy   13w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
node\x20/ 22318           deploy   14w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
node\x20/ 22318           deploy   15w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
node\x20/ 22318           deploy   16w      REG              202,1 3541729280     791684 /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
```

How do I release these files?

**Update 2**

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ sudo ls -l /proc/22318/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 0 -> socket:[74749956]
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 1 -> socket:[74749958]
lr-x------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 10 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 12 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 13 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 14 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 15 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 16 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 17 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 18 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 19 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 2 -> socket:[74749960]
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 20 -> /data/app/shared/logs/production.log (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 21 -> socket:[74750302]
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 22 -> socket:[74750303]
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 3 -> socket:[74749962]
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 4 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
lr-x------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 5 -> pipe:[74749978]
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 6 -> pipe:[74749978]
lr-x------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 7 -> pipe:[74749979]
l-wx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 8 -> pipe:[74749979]
lrwx------ 1 deploy deploy 64 Apr  6 10:05 9 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
```

---

```
ubuntu@app1:~$ ps aux | grep node
deploy   22318  0.0 12.7 1277192 129844 ?      Ssl   2019 173:38 node /data/app/releases/20180904094535/app.js
ubuntu   30665  0.0  0.0  12944   972 pts/0    S+   10:09   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

Comment: The file might still be held open by the process. `lsof +D /data/`

Comment: I got `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: This maybe because my disk is full. I also ran `sync && sync && sync` but still `df -h` shows `/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /`. But `sudo du -h` shows `4.4G /`

Comment: The process `22318` needs to be restarted, if it can be. Can you post the output of `ls -l /proc/22318/fd`?

Comment: @franklinsijo I have posted above. This is a legacy server, running a node application. I don't have any experience with node and the previous engineer has left. I can run `kill -9 22318` to kill node but not sure if I'll be able to start it back.

Comment: @franklinsijo I killed and restarted node the app. The space seems to be released. Problem solved!

Comment: Yes restarting the process would have fixed it. In case, you cannot restart the process at the moment, you can truncate the file to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 0):

The files were held up by the node application. Determined using:

```
sudo lsof | grep deleted
```

Restarting the node application solved my problem.

Find node process id `ps aux | grep node`. Then kill node server using `kill -9 <process_id>`. Finally restart node server. In my case `pm2` automatically restarted node.